# Why "A value of type 'Set<ShProblemHive>' can't be returned from the method 'toHive' because it has a return type of 'ShProblemHive'."

Tags: flutter, class, constructor, repository, flutter-hive

I am trying to connect a `Hive` database with domain and a data layer. However, I am struggling to transform my entity data class to a `HiveObject`. With my current approach I receive the error as seen in the title of this post. Other attempts also failed and I start recognizing, I appear to have a lack of understanding, how those constructors work...

So in general, I want to use a `class ShProblem` in the domain layer that has a constructor

```dart
static ShProblem fromEntity(ShmProblemEntity entity) {
    return ShProblem(
      id: entity.id,
      level: entity.level,
    );
  }
```

This constructor shall receive/provide data from/to the data source via an entity class. Getting data from `Hive` should work (not tested, but at least no compile error), however, the other way around does not work as with JSON maps (seen in the `toDocument` constructor), what I used previously with other databases.

```dart
class ShmProblemEntity {
  ShmProblemEntity({required this.id, required this.level, });
  final int id;
  final int level;  

  static ShmProblemEntity fromHive(ShProblemHive hiveObject) {
    return ShmProblemEntity(
      id: hiveObject.id,
      level: hiveObject.level,
    );
  }

   static ShProblemHive toHive() => {
     ShProblemHive(
    id: this.id,
    level: level,
     )
  };

  Map<String, dynamic> toDocument() => {
    "id": id,
    "level": level,
  };
```

So, it is strange to me that `fromHive` throws no error while `toHive` does, though I notice the difference that `fromHive` has the same datatype as the `class` of the constructor while `toHive` has not.

Comment: Try removing the `{}`'s around the return value in `toHive()`. Never coded Flutter, but it would seem on the error message that wrapping the value in `{}` makes it a set.

Comment: You are absolutely right, Joachim. However, just played around and found `toHive() {ShProblemHive(id: id);};` (removing `=>`) to work as well. Would you be so kind and explain the difference of  `toHive() => ShProblemHive(id: id);` and `toHive() {ShProblemHive(id: id);};` I don't find this in the Dart language tour. Also happy to accept your comment as an answer